# Regex to not match a specific string, but with additional check

Tags: regex, python-3.x

So for example I have this string

```
var = 'column1;column2;column3\r\nval1;val2;val3\r\n;val4;val5;val6\r\n'
```

I want to be able to find all `\r\n` and replace it with `temp\r\n`, but I want to ignore `column3\r\n`

Tried to do `^(?!.*column3).*$\r\n` but the \r\n syntax does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a `negative lookbehind`, that is make the substitution when `\r\n` is not preceded by `column3`:

```
re.sub(r'(?<!column3)\r\n', r'temp\r\n', var)
```

For example:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> var = 'column1;column2;column3\r\nval1;val2;val3\r\n;val4;val5;val6\r\n'
>>> new_text = re.sub(r'(?<!column3)\r\n', r'temp\r\n', var)
>>> new_text
'column1;column2;column3\r\nval1;val2;val3temp\r\n;val4;val5;val6temp\r\n'
>>>
```